# model binding html:asp not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I made a dynamic `textarea`'s group that are added in `DOM` dynamically by using `JS`.
Those `textarea`'s, I want them in the `controller`, indeed.
I receive `null` values in the `model.actionLis`t with that code:

Here is the `HTML` generated:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<div><textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[1].probleme"></textarea> <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[1].action"></textarea></div>

<div><textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[2].probleme"></textarea> <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[2].action"></textarea></div>

<div><textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[3].probleme"></textarea><textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[3].action"></textarea></div>

</div>
```

By this `JS`:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div>Probleme: <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[' + x + '].probleme"></textarea> Action: <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="model.actionList[' + x + '].action"></textarea>@*<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>*@</div>'); //add input box
```

Server-side, This is the `controller`:

```
public ActionResult Create(AuditViewModel model)
{...}
```

This is the famous `Viewmodel` part that are interesting here:

```
public class AuditViewModel
    {public List<Actions> actionList { get; set; }}
```

Finally, this is the `Action` class:

```
public class Actions
{
    public string probleme { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
}
```

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Indexing starts from **0** and secondly use it like `actionList[index].SomePeoperty` as actionList is property of your `Model`:

When you write:

```
@model SomeModel

@Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.SomeProperty)
```

it is rendered like:

```
<textarea name="SomeProperty" id="SomeProperty"></textarea>
```

it is not rendered like:

```
<textarea name="model.SomeProperty" id="model.SomeProperty"></textarea>
```

So try it like below:

```
<div>
<textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="actionList[0].probleme"></textarea> 
<textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="actionList[0].action">
</textarea>
</div>

<div>
<textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="actionList[1].probleme"></textarea> 
<textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="actionList[1]action">
</textarea>
</div>

<div>
<textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="actionList[2].probleme"></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="actionList[2].action">
</textarea>
</div>
```